# Disappearing Files While Using Python Fabric

Tags: python, python-3.x, fabric

I'm using fabric to construct a project on a remote server. (Although right now I'm testing on localhost.) There are several file dependencies stored in s3 and a git repo. The git repo was fine until I added the other dependencies, and now one of the folders `/test_fab/smart-targeting-service/classification/` disappears at the end of the script.

Is this a known behavior of Fabric?

I have commented where the files disappear.

```
from fabric.api import *
from fabric.context_managers import cd

env.activate = 'source venv/bin/activate'

def stand_up_smart_targeting():

    sudo('rm -rf test_fab')

    home_directory = run('pwd')

    run('mkdir test_fab')

    sudo('pip3 install virtualenv')

    current_directory = home_directory + '/test_fab'

    files = ['https://s3.amazonaws.com/subnet/file1.tar.gz', 'https://s3.amazonaws.com/subnet/file1.tar.gz']

    with cd(current_directory):

        for file in files:
            run('wget {}'.format(file))
            run('tar -xvzf {}'.format(file.split('/')[len(file.split('/')) - 1]))

         run('git clone https://github.com/smart-targetting-service.git')

    with cd(current_directory + '/smart-targetting-service'):

        run('virtualenv -p python3 venv')

        run('ls')

    with cd(current_directory + '/smart-targetting-service/classification'):

        run('ls')# <-- this command shows the files correctly

        #They disappear here somehow
```

Comment: Your file looks wrong because of the indentation not lining up.  Could you please fix that so that we can get a better understanding of how your code is supposed to work?

Comment: Sure. Sorry about that.